# How to center position:absolute element in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css

I have an slider, which include navigation dots positioned by absolute value. And I want to know how to center those dots by X axis.

Im fine when it's set right: 10%; at the desktop layout.
But mobile have an esthetic issues when the values in %, it just never looks right in the center because of small width.

I have searched a lot, and most popular solution was

```
left: 50%;
right: 50% transform: translateX(50%);
```

But still it works just as left.. Please have an look on jsfiddle code below, I need space between 2nd and 3rd white dot to be cut by white vertical line.

https://jsfiddle.net/dpmango/vk9oc6gt/2/

Thank you for helping in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/vk9oc6gt/3/

`transform:translateX(-50%);` is what you're looking for.

Notice when you apply `transform:translateX(-50%);` it shifts the element by a percentage of **the element's dimensions**, in this case the width because it's an X axis translate, 50% because we specified it and to the left because it's a negative value.

I added it in both the middle dots div and the middle white line:

```
.center-line {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-dots {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

If you need vertically centered dots too, you can go with this https://jsfiddle.net/vk9oc6gt/4/ using:

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score -1):

why dont u use this? -  `.owl-dots{width: 100%, text-align:center; left:0;}`